# How to remove duplicate rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I want to remove duplicate rows from the result of the following query.

My table looks like this:

```
idx     writetime           iu_id   iu_nickname ib_idx  Gamecnt
---------------------------------------------------------------
1456885 2017-11-27 02:51:00 csw0322 csw0322     885452  2
1456886 2017-11-27 02:51:00 csw0322 csw0322     885452  2
1456887 2017-11-27 02:51:00 csw0322 csw0322     885454  3
1456888 2017-11-27 02:51:00 csw0322 csw0322     885454  3
1456889 2017-11-27 02:51:00 csw0322 csw0322     885454  3
1456893 2017-11-27 04:29:00 csw0322 csw0322     885457  2
1456894 2017-11-27 04:29:00 csw0322 csw0322     885457  2
1456895 2017-11-27 04:29:00 csw0322 csw0322     885456  2
1456896 2017-11-27 04:29:00 csw0322 csw0322     885456  2
```

The result I want is this:

```
idx     writetime           iu_id   iu_nickname ib_idx  Gamecnt
---------------------------------------------------------------
1456885 2017-11-27 02:51:00 csw0322 csw0322     885452  2
1456887 2017-11-27 02:51:00 csw0322 csw0322     885454  3
1456893 2017-11-27 04:29:00 csw0322 csw0322     885457  2
1456895 2017-11-27 04:29:00 csw0322 csw0322     885456  2
```

I tried this query, but I can not get results.

```
SELECT 
    a.idx, a.writetime, 
    a.iu_id, a.iu_nickname, 
    a.ib_idx, 
    COUNT(a.ib_idx) OVER (PARTITION BY a.ib_idx) AS Gamecnt 
FROM   
    bet_log AS a 
INNER JOIN 
    info_betting AS b ON a.ib_idx = b.ib_idx 
WHERE  
    a.ib_idx IN (SELECT a.ib_idx 
                 FROM bet_log AS a 
                 GROUP BY a.ib_idx 
                 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ And what do you mean by "I can not get results"? Do you get incorrect results, an error message, no results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`row_number()` is a typical method:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM (SELECT bl.idx, bl.writetime, bl.iu_id, bl.iu_nickname, bl.ib_idx, 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY bl.writetime, bl.iu_id, bl.iu_nickname, bl.ib_idx ORDER BY bl.idx) as seqnum
      FROM bet_log bl INNER JOIN
           info_betting ib 
           ON bl.ib_idx = ib.ib_idx 
     ) b
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `group by`

```
 select min(idx),  writetime, iu_id, iu_nickname, ib_idx, Gamecnt
 from your_table
 group by writetime, iu_id, iu_nickname, ib_idx, Gamecnt
```

since `your_table` is probably the SQL you provide then

```
 select min(idx),  writetime, iu_id, iu_nickname, ib_idx, Gamecnt
 from (
  SELECT a.idx, 
   a.writetime, 
   a.iu_id, 
   a.iu_nickname, 
   a.ib_idx, 
   Count(a.ib_idx) 
     OVER( 
       partition BY a.ib_idx) AS Gamecnt 
  FROM   bet_log AS a 
   INNER JOIN info_betting AS b 
           ON a.ib_idx = b.ib_idx 
  WHERE  a.ib_idx IN (SELECT a.ib_idx 
                FROM   bet_log AS a 
                GROUP  BY a.ib_idx 
                HAVING Count(*) > 1) 
 ) t
 group by writetime, iu_id, iu_nickname, ib_idx, Gamecnt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT distinct  
       a.writetime, 
       a.iu_id, 
       a.iu_nickname, 
       a.ib_idx, 
       Count(a.ib_idx) 
         OVER( 
           partition BY a.ib_idx) AS Gamecnt 
FROM   bet_log AS a 
       INNER JOIN info_betting AS b 
               ON a.ib_idx = b.ib_idx 
WHERE  a.ib_idx IN (SELECT a.ib_idx 
                    FROM   bet_log AS a 
                    GROUP  BY a.ib_idx 
                    HAVING Count(*) > 1)
```

Comment: and where is the `idx`? ;)

Comment: This will not return the `idx` column at all.

Answer (score 0):

Add another group by at the very end, this is more efficient than using a select distinct.

```
 SELECT a.idx, 
           a.writetime, 
           a.iu_id, 
           a.iu_nickname, 
           a.ib_idx, 
           Count(a.ib_idx) 
             OVER( 
               partition BY a.ib_idx) AS Gamecnt 
    FROM   bet_log AS a 
           INNER JOIN info_betting AS b 
                   ON a.ib_idx = b.ib_idx 
    WHERE  a.ib_idx IN (SELECT a.ib_idx 
                        FROM   bet_log AS a 
                        GROUP  BY a.ib_idx 
                        HAVING Count(*) > 1) 
    GROUP BY 
           a.idx, 
           a.writetime, 
           a.iu_id, 
           a.iu_nickname, 
           a.ib_idx
```